# Lua library/code for parsing XML

Tags: xml, lua

I'm looking for a pure Lua library for parsing XML files. It doesn't have to be a validating parser, and it doesn't matter if it's DOM or SAX.

The best resource I've found so far is the [Lua Users wiki page on XML libraries](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaXml) (which seems to be down as I type this; check the [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cR5h8KW5o2MJ:lua-users.org/wiki/LuaXml+lua+xml+parser&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca&client=safari) version for now). What experience have you had with the code on this page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Lua-only solution, I've heard that [LuaXML](http://web.archive.org/web/20040703165638/http://www.passtheaardvark.com/lua/LuaXML-0.0.0.tgz) is good (there are two libraries with the same name, one in pure Lua and other with a C module).

I'm currently using LuaExpat, that are bindings to the well know Expat XML parser.

Comment: I'll probably look at LuaXML.  As I said, I need a Lua-only solution.  It's kind of disconcerting that the library may be considered abandonware.

Comment: Hello, I had a similar question in this issue, since you two obviously figured it out, can I ask you to have a look at my question?