# Read an attrribute from xml in Lua

Tags: lua

How to Read an attrribute from xml in Lua

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua library/code for parsing XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535844/lua-library-code-for-parsing-xml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"lua xml" in a google search brings up http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaXml as first Result.
Another search for the first example "Luaxml" give me the homepage of it, with an nice example on the start page: http://viremo.eludi.net/LuaXML/